# Определение размера блока

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте! На JavaScript я определяю высоту дива. Но она определяется не всегда, внутри дива - картинки, видимо, иногда они не успевают загрузиться. Не подскажете, что можно сделать? Скрипт стоит в самом конце страницы.

```
$('div.banner-right').first().height()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Может быть $(document).ready поможет?

Answer (score 3):

Используйте [load event](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/) для картинок:

```
<img src="book.png" alt="Book" id="book" />

$('#book').load(function() {
  // Здесь считаем высоту
});
```

Comment: Ну и кроме того, указывать размеры картинок тоже может быть вариантом.

Comment: Спасибо, просто у меня в этом диве заранее неизвестное кол-во картинок неизвестного размера, поэтому $(document).ready больше подошел.